# ks.cfg file + how to fit the ks.cfg for PXE server

Tags: linux, pxe-boot, kickstart, tftp, vmlinuz

I want to configure the ks.cfg file under PXE server 
So I will able to install linux from PXE server
PXE server include the files ( initrd.img & vmlinuz ) and the ks.cfg

My default ks.cfg was taken from the original initrd.img ( from ISO file )

And now I need to edit the ks.cfg in order to use this file by the PXE server

My question is – what need to change in the ks.cfg in order to work with PXE server
For example

I guess all

```
  /tmp/cdrom
```

in the original ks.cfg need to change to

```
 /mnt/source
```

and need to add this lines also

```
     nfs --server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dir=/RedHat-DIR
     network --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp --nodns
```

There are maybe other changes but I need help

Comment: have you read https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html ?